# ValangValidator alternate class with spring 5

Tags: spring5

Please suggest alternate class for org.springmodules.validation.valang.ValangValidator, which is part of spring module validation 0.8. However the JDKVersion inside it is not supported in Spring5.x frameworks.  So i need to migrate from ValangValidator to something else for file validation.  What is the best alternate for this?

Comment: <bean id="storeValangValidator" class="org.springmodules.validation.valang.ValangValidator">
  <property name="valang">
   <value>

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storeValangValidator' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/storeHierarchy.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/JdkVersion